# Wordpress Display Content in Sidebar on Specific Post/Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not sure exactly what I am looking for in the api so I'm going to ask here. On a post/page, I want the ability to have a piece of text display on the sidebar ONLY that content. The content to be display is to be set as an attribute or something similar in the edit area of that post only.

Is there a way of doing this and where do I look in the api?

Comment: You are not be clear enough. Did you try using text widget? Under appearances / widgets..

Comment: Text widget appears on every page. I want this widget to only show on specified post.

Comment: So create a custom field containing your text block, and then call that.

Comment: You can create sidebar areas and pick a special sidebar area for that page. Try out sidebar plugins http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/dynamic-sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Using a text widget as already mentioned, you can use the Widget Logic plugin and use an if statement to display that widget only on the post you want.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for logic to do this here it is:

1. In your post you have access to custom variable so create one which you will then access in sidebar and if that is true then a widget can be shown else it does not need to be.
2. You need to access this custom variable outside post loop which you can use by using global variables and assign its value to that.
3. In your widget you need to look at globalvariables and check the value of above and then do your if else logic to show or hide parts of content in sidebar.

A good starting point for this can be [this tutorial](http://www.studionashvegas.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-dynamic-sidebar-controlled-with-custom-fields-in-wordpress/) which does show twitter or facebook posts based on custom variable on post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin and either select pages, post-types or even a comma separated list of post ids http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/